# Get myprofile.php after registering with session containing the user_username

Tags: php, session-cookies

I can get the users to register and the data is getting inserted into the database. However, I can store the `user_username` in the session.
My `registrationprocess.php` code is

```
<?php
require '../_inc/db.php';
session_start();
if(isset($_REQUEST['signup_button'])){
$user_email=$_REQUEST['user_email'];
$user_firstname=$_REQUEST['user_firstname'];
$user_lastname=$_REQUEST['user_lastname'];
$user_username=$_REQUEST['user_username'];
$user_password=$_REQUEST['user_password'];
//echo "$user_username";
// echo 'working';
$sql1="INSERT INTO user(user_firstname,user_lastname,user_email,user_username,user_password) VALUES('$user_firstname','$user_lastname','$user_email','$user_username','$user_password')";
mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());
//include("authenticationforupload.php");
$_SESSION['user_username'] = $user_username;
echo $_SESSION['user_username'];
header('Location: ../updateprofileone.php?user_username=$user_username');
    }
?>
```

However, in the `updateprofileone.php`, the address is not containing the variable `$user_username`.

It shows `updateprofileone.php?user_username=$user_username`.

Any help?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and need to learn about PHP `'`-quoted strings: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Comment: You should be explicit in what type of HTTP request you accept (e.g. you should only accept POST for this type of action.)

Answer (score 1):

You are not concatenating the value of $user_username correctly.

I have wrote the correct line for header().

header('Location: ../updateprofileone.php?user_username='.$user_username);

Put $user_username outside of string, so it can render the value.

Comment: Or if you want to use php variable inside quoted string, use " (double-quote) instead of ' (single-quote).

Comment: This works. But how can I store the value of the `$user_username` in the session?

Comment: Are you starting session in updateprofileone.php file?

If you have session_start() in updateprofileone.php file, you should be able to echo $_SESSION['user_username']

Comment: I have `index.php` where users register before being redirected to `myprofile.php`. **Would it be better if I use `session_start()` in the `registrationprocess.php` (the process which registers a new user and gets called from the form in the `index.php`)?** I hope I'm clear about my question!

Comment: No. A good scenario would be you create a header file. Put session_start() in that header file and include it in all of your pages. May be you are already doing it for MySQL connection.

Please note: You need to start session  on every page in which you want to access/modify session variables.

Answer (score 0):

try to change this line:

`header('Location: ../updateprofileone.php?user_username=$user_username');`

with this:

`header("Location: ../updateprofileone.php?user_username=$user_username");`

OR if you want to make it global or "underground" you can set it into a session like:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $user_username;
```

so you can call it with this `$_SESSION['username'];` from other pages, but make sure that you initialize the session at the top of each page you want to use it with

```
`session_start();`
```

Hope can help you.

Comment: Thanks @jbaires. But `header('Location: ../updateprofileone.php?user_username='.$user_username);` which was provided by @haseeb-khiljiworks perfectly.